# USB port mouse is detected but doesn't control screen pointer

Tags: usb, mouse

The mouse wheel works - switches between screen 1 and 2. And, the
laptop mouse touchpad is able to control the screen pointer.

```
sudo dmesg -c

[ 3264.042714] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 6`

dmesg

[ 3341.417267] usb 2-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3341.515592] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c045
[ 3341.515601] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3341.515606] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[ 3341.515611] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 3341.520421] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:046D:C045.0005/input/input22
[ 3341.520830] hid-generic 0003:046D:C045.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c045 Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1e5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

xsetpointer -l |grep Pointer

2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"  [XExtensionPointer]
10: "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"   [XExtensionPointer]
```

ASUS Laptop m/n X52F
Lubuntu v16.04

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a loser mouse. This is a common issue when your computer is located in a dusty environment, or near other possible sources of pollution, like spider cobwebs.

Unplug the mouse. Turn it over. Look inside the hole(using light if needed) and confirm that there is pollution inside, corrupting the input. Use air or something else to get rid of it.